# Rename and delete fields in the attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, delete

I am using QGIS V3.22.6

I have an attribute table with unnecessary fields that I wish to delete. I also wish to rename some of the fields.

I cannot see how to do this using the Attribute Table Editor.

Comment: What is the type of source data? In QGIS, some types don't support renaming and deleting fields, e.g. KML.

Comment: [Refactor fields](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectortable.html#refactor-fields)

Answer (score 6):

using QGIS 3.28.4, you can:

1. right click on the shapefile showing at the Layers panel select Properties
   [image: properties]
2. then inside the Fields tab you should select the Toggle editing mode
   [image: editing]

When editing mode is active, you can delete, renames the columns.